# Java Scanner of an InputStream

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I try to use a scanner on an inputStream. My file looks like:

```
Eventlabel  -0.0630    2013.0   38.4    25.1
0.01        -0.0590    2009.0   23.2    21.6
0.02        -0.0564    2006.4   19.7    21.2
0.03        -0.0540    2004.0   23.6    24.3
```

Its tab-delimited. I tried following code:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())) {
            String fileString = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error while reading multipart request", e);
    }
```

The output look fine, but for the Event label is sometimes a new line. If I extract the fileString into a String[] with split("\t"), the value of Event labellooks like " Event label". But the "whitespace" between " Event label" isnt a whitspace (I tested, guess is a new \A). So maybe there is something wrong with my pattern ("\A").

I cant use the scanner with the Delimiter tab, cause sometimes there are some extra information before my tables. Someone has another brilliant idea, how I can use the scanner and get all of my table information +  special information?

EDIT: 
If I use the matrix

```
1       2205    2936    15122   9193
0.15    -0.0186 1968.6  19.2    27.0
0.16    -0.0154 1965.4  18.9    28.4
0.17    -0.0127 1962.7  16.8    26.5
```

The first value (1) is "deleted" and not in my fileString :/

Comment: You might want to consider using a BufferedReader rather than a Scanner. You can use readLine() which you can then parse as you wish. You could use a Scanner with nextLine() which will give you pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Can I use BufferedReader with a Charset? Had ByteArrayInput before and my specialchars like micromillimeter ( working for scientists) are not in my fileString. So i tried Scanner.

Comment: BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Comment: Same problem with that leading \A . Maybe there is something wrong in my file. But if I open that with notepad++ there is no char before my "event label"

Comment: I don't remember a \A in regex.

Comment: \A stands for :start of a string

Comment: \A is the beginning of the input, which means using it in Scanner may be unpredictable. It should only match once at the beginning of the string. What is your rational for using it as a delimiter?